# Orange 3.15 GUI window size issue (Windows 8.1)

Tags: orange

I'd just like to report an annoying GUI bug I am experimenting under Windows 8.1 using Orange 3.15.

The work space available doesn't size up with the window making the use of the software quite frustrating.

[Here](https://youtu.be/cQu5RQNKc8M) is a video of the bug.

Does anyone have a fix for that by any chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue: https://github.com/biolab/orange3/issues/3193

It is caused by a bug in Qt 5.9.6 ([QTBUG-16252](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-68939)). You should downgrade Qt to 5.9.5.

To do that open the "Orange Command Prompt" from the Window 8.1 'Start Screen' (start menu) and type in `conda install qt=5.9.5`